# Constant velocity rotating helix position

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, multilinear-algebra

I need to find the parametric equations for a helix that is rotating on its axis. The initial helix position is given by the equations$$x_0=\cos(a) , y_0=\sin(a) , z_0=a$$and rotating on its axis with a constant angular velocity $\omega=1$. This translates to a velocity vector $$v=[-y\hat{i}, x\hat{j},0\hat{k}]$$ My question is how do I find the helix position with respect to time i.e. $$x(a,t),y(a,t),z(a,t)$$
At first I naively thought I could just integrate the velocity wrt to time, t, which would result in $$x=-yt+c_1$$ $$y=xt+c_2$$ and after solving for the constants of integration using my initial position I get $$x=\cos(a)-t \sin(a)$$ $$y=\sin(a)+t \cos(a)$$ $$z=a$$
This is not correct since x and y are functions of t and therefore I assume my integration is wrong. Also I plotted this in matlab and although the helix does spin about its axis it also expands radially. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your situation, but it seems like you would want the time dependence to be inside the trigonometric function arguments for say x and y.  For example, a form like:

$x\left(a,t\right)=\cos\left(a+\omega t\right)$
$y\left(a,t\right)=\sin\left(a+\omega t\right)$

The z component is just linear:

$z\left(a,t\right) = a+v_{0}t$

where $v_{0}$ is the constant velocity/speed.

This would provide for a helix moving in the z-direction as the axis.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This actually works perfectly for what I wanted. I don't think it's exactly what I had in mind but then again Im not sure I was thinking of it correctly in the first place. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "$v_0$ is the constant velocity/speed", what is that velocity? All i am imposing on the system is $\omega$ and my helix ranges through the parameter a. So if I undergo solid body rotation on I know there should be a z component velocity but I don't understand how to derive what that would be.